# performance of JPA Find by attribute IN VS find by attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am relatively new to Hibernate JPA, so I have this quick question. I want to know, in terms of performance, which is better between:

1. Calling `findByAttributeIn(List<Integer> attrList)` once with 1000 `attr` in an `attrList` vs
2. Calling `findByAttribute(Integer attr)` 1000 times with different values for `attr` each time.

Assuming the methods are in a JPA Repository as shown below:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Integer>{
  
  List<MyEntity> myEntityList findByAttributeIn(List<Integer> attrList);
  Optional<MyEntity> entity findByAttribute(Integer attr);
 
}
```

My initial assumption is that `IN` ( `findByAttributeIn(List<Integer> attrList`) will perform faster since is a single connection call to the DB but then again you are calling it for a 1000 items. My question is that will there be a significant difference between it and the latter (`findByAttribute(Integer attr)`) when it comes to speed?

Comment: Presumably "in" only requires a single round-trip.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Yes that is my assumption as well, I just want to know if there will be a significant difference between the two in terms of processing speed.

Comment: Usually, `findByAttributeIn` will be faster because it only needs a single database round trip.